# I accidentally created a GPT label on a sdb that already was in a VG : WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q

Tags: linux, lvm, uuid

I accidentally created on GPT label on /dev/sdb on a production server which belonged to the `ubuntu-vg`.

Before the change :

```shell
$ df -h /
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   88G   74G   11G  88% /
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all
of the space (an extra 20971520 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? f
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 85.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name       Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                          bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4         /boot
 3      1076MB  75.2GB  74.1GB               ubuntu-vg

$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <69.00g    0
  /dev/sdb   ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <20.00g    0
```

The change :

```shell
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) p
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

(parted) q
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

After the change :

```shell
$ sudo pvs
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <69.00g    0
  [unknown]  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a-m  <20.00g    0
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to /dev/sdb).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter.
$ sudo pvs
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <69.00g    0
  [unknown]  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a-m  <20.00g    0
```

I tried this :

```shell
$ sudo vgck --updatemetadata ubuntu-vg
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to /dev/sdb).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
$ sudo pvscan --cache
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  pvscan[1018603] PV /dev/sda3 online.
$ sudo pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/ubuntu-vg --uuid "CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q" /dev/sdb
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 3CHhp6-yMvu-Fnqj-8usZ-EHp8-k88B-Jm8MK3.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter.
$ echo $?
5
$ sudo pvck -t /dev/sdb
  TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
  Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter.

$ sudo pvs /dev/sda3
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <69.00g    0
$ df -h /
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   88G   74G   11G  88% /
$ sudo vgreduce --removemissing --verbose /dev/ubuntu-vg
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  There are 1 physical volumes missing.
  Archiving volume group "ubuntu-vg" metadata (seqno 12).
  WARNING: Partial LV ubuntu-lv needs to be repaired or removed.
  There are still partial LVs in VG ubuntu-vg.
  To remove them unconditionally use: vgreduce --removemissing --force.
  WARNING: Proceeding to remove empty missing PVs.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  There are 1 physical volumes missing.
  Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/ubuntu-vg" (seqno 13).
administrateur@par-glpinetwork:/var/www/glpi/config$ sudo pvdisplay -m
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q.
  WARNING: VG ubuntu-vg is missing PV CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: Couldn't find all devices for LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv while checking used and assumed devices.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <69.00 GiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              17663
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          17663
  PV UUID               3CHhp6-yMvu-Fnqj-8usZ-EHp8-k88B-Jm8MK3

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 17662:
    Logical volume      /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    Logical extents     0 to 17662

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               [unknown]
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               20.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5119
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5119
  PV UUID               CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 5118:
    Logical volume      /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    Logical extents     17663 to 22781
```

HELP, how can I fix this ?

Comment: if sdb was added as a raid one member, then the same procedure would be used when a drive fails imho

Comment: @djdomi Nope. There is no RAID configuration here.

Comment: @djdomi Hi, I found [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314507/135038). Can I safely do a `sudo pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/archive/ubuntu-vg_00007-1330575295.vg --uuid "CdlY5k-IynC-hYTX-hH3h-HaLC-KAqy-n4h38q" /dev/sdb`